# How to iterate over a dictionary in Python using recursion

Tags: python

Only one problem is how to convert the python dictionary of tree paths into a tree according to the format below.

How to convert a python dictionary:

```
{
  "example": {
    "dir2": {
      "file4": {},
      "file5": {}
    },
    "dir1": {
      "file1": {},
      "file2": {},
      "dir5": {},
      "dir4": {
        "file3": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to look like this:

```
{"name": "example",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "dir2",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "file4"
        },
        {
          "name": "file5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "dir1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "file1"
        },
        {
          "name": "file2"
        },
        {
          "name": "dir5",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "dir4",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "file3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I run the following:

```
def convert_dict(dic):
    name = list(dic.keys())[0]
    d = {'name': name}
    if dic[name]:
        d['children']=[convert_dict(dic[name][x]) for x in list(dic[name].keys())]
    return d

print(json.dumps(convert_dict(tree_dict), indent=2))
```

but I get:

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "file4"
    },
    {
      "name": "file1"
    }
  ]
}
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: What if there is more than one top-level key? The main data structure should be a list then, because you cannot have multiple `name` keys.

Comment: How do you differentiate `dir5` and `file2` (i.e. one has `children`, one doesn't)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For consistency, the top-level data-structure should be a list, just as all the nested dicts are converted into lists:

```
def convert_dict(dic):
    result = []
    for k, v in dic.items():
        d = {'name': k}
        if v:
            d['children'] = convert_dict(v)
        result.append(d)
    return result

>>> convert_dict(d)
[{'children': [{'children': [{'name': 'file4'}, {'name': 'file5'}],
                'name': 'dir2'},
               {'children': [{'name': 'file1'},
                             {'name': 'file2'},
                             {'name': 'dir5'},
                             {'children': [{'name': 'file3'}], 'name': 'dir4'}],
                'name': 'dir1'}],
  'name': 'example'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a comprehension:

```
def convert_dict(d):
    return [ dict(zip(("name","children"),filter(None,nc)))
             for k,v in d.items() for nc in [(k,convert_dict(v))] ]
```

output:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(convert_dict(tree_dict),indent=2))

[
  {
    "name": "example",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "dir2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "file4"
          },
          {
            "name": "file5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "dir1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "file1"
          },
          {
            "name": "file2"
          },
          {
            "name": "dir5"
          },
          {
            "name": "dir4",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "file3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```